^C appears when I use python debugpy in vscode
I just wanted use the Python debugger.
When I press Ctrl + F5 in VSCode to use the Python debugger, ^C appears in the terminal, followed by a cd command, and then the Python file is executed.
Like this:
user@DESKTOP MINGW64 ~/Desktop/SSA (master)
$ ^C

user@DESKTOP MINGW64 ~/Desktop/SSA (master)
$  cd c:\\Users\\isagk\\Desktop\\SSA ; /usr/bin/env c:\\Users\\isagk\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python.exe c:\\Users\\isagk\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-python.debugpy-2024.6.0-win32-x64\\bundled\\libs\\debugpy\\adapter/../..\\debugpy\\launcher 54240 -- C:\\Users\\isagk\\Desktop\\SSA\\test.py

What happened?
I tried changing the key binding, changing terminal settings, and updating the Python extension.
I would expect it to just run the Python file without ^C or something when I press Ctrl + F5.

Does this answer your question? VS Code 1.88 inserts ^C before running a debug configuration again. Why?

I believe this is normal. ^C is how the terminal writes CTRL+C (the keyboard interrupt keybind). When you run your program, you don’t want anything else running in that terminal instance, and you definitely don't want incomplete lines in your instance, so VS Code automatically calls ^C for you.
